# Python function Converting an integer to bins as per given interval

Tags: python

I am trying to convert an integer (`num`) to bins as per given interval. the bin size (intervals) are `[1, 200), [200, 400), [400, 800), [800, 1200), [1200, num]`

I'am doing it in a crude way ...

```
def create_bins(num):
    """Create Bins as per given intervals."""
    s1, s2, s3, s4 = 199, 200, 400, 400
    if num > 1200:
        res = [s1, s2, s3, s4, num - (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4)]
    elif num < 1200 and num >= 800:
        res = [s1, s2, s3, num - (s1 + s2 + s3)]
    elif num < 800 and num >= 400:
        res = [s1, s2, num - (s1 + s2)]
    elif num < 400 and num >= 200:
        res = [s1, num - s1]
    else:
        res = [num]

    return res
```

this function for `create_bins(1041)` returns `[199, 200, 400, 242]` which is correct. However, I'am sure there are better ways to get it done...

Comment: (199, 200, 400, 242) is a quite strange bin arrangement. Why not (200, 400, 441) or (41, 400, 600)? Both of those options would only have one irregular entry instead of two.

Comment: Better yet, (147, 347 547) preserves the sum and has a constant differential.

Comment: @Reinderien the bin arrangement is tariff structure for electricity consumption in units. There is some anamoly in billings. To check the extent of it money wise, i needed those bins.

Answer (score 3):

**Bug: 1200 slips through the conditional cracks**. Your code returns `[1200]`,
but it should return `[199, 200, 400, 400, 1]`. The fix is simple: use
greater-than-or-equal for the first comparison.

**An alternative approach: iterate over the bin sizes**. If you were
to include
a huge bin size at the end, you could just iterate and subtract as you go,
which simplifies the conditional logic a fair bit.

```
def create_bins(n):
    xs = []
    for bin_size in [199, 200, 400, 400, float('inf')]:
        if n <= bin_size:
            xs.append(n)
            return xs
        else:
            xs.append(bin_size)
            n -= bin_size
```

**Possible next steps**. (1) Depending on your use case, validate
that `n` is a positive integer. (2) Take the bin sizes
as an optional parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of your program, as I understand it, is this:

- Input: a list of bin widths and a value (`num`).
- Output: a list that starts with the bin widths of bins that precede the value, and the position of the value within the last bin.

Three things immediately jump out to me. First, the variable names `s1, s2, s3, s4` tell me that a list is a better way to hold this data than individual variables. Second, all of the values of your bins are hard coded into the function, meaning a new set of bins requires a new function. Lastly, the repetitive nature of the `if` blocks warrants some sort of loop. Let's address these in order.

I'm going to be very verbose in showing my code changes so that my thinking as I make changes is (hopefully) clearer.

#### Replace numbered variables with a list

The first thing to do is replace `s1, s2,`  etc. with a list with a better name. Then, we calculate results using operations on the new list.

```py
def create_bins(num):
    """Create Bins as per given intervals."""
    bin_widths = [199, 200, 400, 400]
    if num > 1200:
        res = bin_widths[0:4] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:4)]
    elif num < 1200 and num >= 800:
        res = bin_widths[0:3] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:3])]
    elif num < 800 and num >= 400:
        res = bin_widths[0:2] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:2])]
    elif num < 400 and num >= 200:
        res = bin_widths[0:1] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:1])]
    else:
        res = bin_widths[0:0] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:0])]

    return res
```

I've left in redundancy in the code to emphasize that every branch does the same thing, just with a different subset of the `bin_width` list. This will make defining the loop easier.

Now, let's add even more redundancy to calculate the values in the `if` expressions.

```py
def create_bins(num):
    """Create Bins as per given intervals."""
    bin_widths = [199, 200, 400, 400]
    if num > 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:4]):
        res = bin_widths[0:4] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:4)]
    elif num < 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:4]) and num >= 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:3]):
        res = bin_widths[0:3] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:3])]
    elif num < 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:3]) and num >= 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:2]):
        res = bin_widths[0:2] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:2])]
    elif num < 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:2]) and num >= 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:1]):
        res = bin_widths[0:1] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:1])]
    else:
        res = bin_widths[0:0] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:0])]

    return res
```

My point here is to eliminate all of the bare numbers (`1200`, `800`, and the like) and calculate these from the data. If you have the bin widths, you don't need to calculate the boundaries. Let the computer do that.

#### Generalize to any list

Since we no longer need to know the specific bin widths in your example, we can make `bin_widths` a parameter of the function.

```py
def create_bins(num, bin_widths):
    """Create Bins as per given intervals."""
    if num > 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:4]):
        res = bin_widths[0:4] + [num - sum(bin_widths)]
    elif num < 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:4]) and num >= 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:3]):
        res = bin_widths[0:3] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:3])]
    elif num < 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:3]) and num >= 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:2]):
        res = bin_widths[0:2] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:2])]
    elif num < 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:2]) and num >= 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:1]):
        res = bin_widths[0:1] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:1])]
    else:
        res = bin_widths[0:0] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:0])]

    return res
```

Now, let's make this function work for lists of bin widths that aren't exactly of length 4.

#### Replacing `if-elif-else` with a loop

Let's look closely at one of the middle `elif` blocks.

```py
    elif num < 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:3]) and num >= 1 + sum(bin_widths[0:2]):
        res = bin_widths[0:2] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0:2])]
```

The `elif` line checks whether the value `num` is within the range of the current bin. If this is true, the next line calculates the resulting list. This will be the body of the loop. The only thing that changes from `elif` to `elif` is the index in the brackets, so let's make that our loop variable.

```py
def create_bins(num, bin_widths):
    """Create Bins as per given intervals."""
    for index in range(len(bin_widths)):
        if num < 1 + sum(bin_widths[0 : index + 1]) and num >= 1 + sum(bin_widths[0 : index]):
            res = bin_widths[0 : index] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0 : index])]
            break
    
    return res
```

There is a problem with this loop. It cannot handle the case where the value `num` is past the last bin. In that case, it will exit the loop without assigning a value to `res`, resulting in an error when it tries to return. To fix this, we'll return from inside the loop and use exiting the loop as a condition to return the value from the first `if` block in the original code.

```py
def create_bins(num, bin_widths):
    """Create Bins as per given intervals."""
    for index in range(len(bin_widths)):
        if num < 1 + sum(bin_widths[0 : index + 1]) and num >= 1 + sum(bin_widths[0 : index]):
            return bin_widths[0 : index] + [num - sum(bin_widths[0 : index])]
    
    return bin_widths + [num - sum(bin_widths)]
```

At this point, this code is pretty good. It works for any list of any length. But, there's some redundant calculations. Let's give those repeated expressions names.

```py
def create_bins(num, bin_widths):
    """Create Bins as per given intervals."""
    for index in range(len(bin_widths)):
        prior_bins = bin_widths[0 : index]
        lower_bound = sum(prior_bins)
        upper_bound = lower_bound + bin_widths[index]
        if num < 1 + upper_bound and num >= 1 + lower_bound:
            return prior_bins + [num - lower_bound]
    
    return bin_widths + [num - sum(bin_widths)]
```

Now for a bit of simplification, notice that since we are looping through the `bin_widths` list in order, we already know that `num >= 1 + lower_bound` since `num < 1 + upper_bound` was false in the previous loop iteration. So, let's delete that and simplify.

```py
def create_bins(num, bin_widths):
    """Create Bins as per given intervals."""
    for index in range(len(bin_widths)):
        prior_bins = bin_widths[0 : index]
        lower_bound = sum(prior_bins)
        upper_bound = lower_bound + bin_widths[index]
        if num < 1 + upper_bound:
            return prior_bins + [num - lower_bound]
    
    return bin_widths + [num - sum(bin_widths)]
```

Finally, we can do an optimization. Creating a sublist of `bin_widths` on every loop iteration and calculating its sum can get very slow when the list gets large. We can store the previously calculated upper bounds and use those to simplify.

```py
def create_bins(num, bin_widths):
    """Create Bins as per given intervals."""
    upper_bound = 0
    for index in range(len(bin_widths)):
        upper_bound += bin_widths[index]
        lower_bound = upper_bound - bin_widths[index]
        if num < 1 + upper_bound:
            return bin_widths[0 : index] + [num - lower_bound]
    
    return bin_widths + [num - sum(bin_widths)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Restructuring your `if` checks:

You can check each bin like this:

```py
def create_bins(num):
    """Create Bins as per given intervals."""
    s1, s2, s3, s4 = 199, 200, 400, 400

    if num < 200:
        res = [num]
    elif 200 <= num < 400:
        res = [s1, num - s1]
    elif 400 <= num < 800:
        res = [s1, s2, num - (s1 + s2)]
    elif 800 <= num < 1200:
        res = [s1, s2, s3, num - (s1 + s2 + s3)]
    else:
        res = [s1, s2, s3, s4, num - (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4)]

    return res
```

Where now your num checks are within a single statement, and are, IMO, mathematically easier to read

## Type Hints

Type hints are nice to see at a glance what inputs a function takes and what it will return:

```py
from typing import List


def create_bins(num: int) -> List[int]:
    ...
```

Note, if you are on python > 3.8, you can simply use:

```py
def create_bins(num: int) -> list[int]:
    ...
```

Comment: But type hints are useless without a tool that checks your code and makes sure the types match everywhere. The way you present it, it sounds like these hints do anything by themselves. They don’t. Python completely ignores them.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I disagree, I never said they do anything. They are "hints", and I present them as a way to, at a glance, see what types a function might take. Nothing more